# In Cocoa how to resize an Image and animate the resizing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image and make an animation of the resizing.
The idea is to have an image that start with very little dimensions (0.0001,0.0001) and gradually grows till it arrives to its original size (1.0,1.0).
To do that I'm trying to use

> setAffineTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale

but it doesn't work at all...
this code:

> [self.myImage.layer setAffineTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0001,0.0001)];

doesn't give any error or warning but doesn't transform the image...

and for the animation I'm getting an error...
I'm using this code:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:3.0];
[[myImage animator] setAffineTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0)];
```

and I'm getting the error:

> NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:setAffineTransform:] called!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by my self... If anyone has the same necessity here's the solution:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:3.0];
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(102.0, 59.0, 608.0, 533.0); //give the new dimensions here... first 2 numbers are the position of the object (X,Y) and other 2 numbers are the dimensions (width, height)
[[myImage animator] setFrame:rect];
```